# Trigger Jenkins job from Argo CD manually

Tags: jenkins, cicd, argocd, argo-workflows

I have a requirement to trigger Jenkins job from ArgoCD manually. It should not trigger as post deployment action. This intervention should be done manually as separate stage in ArgoCD.

Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: you want to manually trigger jenkins, but from Argo CD? ArgoCD is Continuous Deployment system; typically your CI (ie jenkins) would invoke your CD system. If you really want Argo to invoke jenkins manually, which is absolutely wild, then you should just make a new application that contains a `kind: Job` which invokes Jenkins. My 2 cents - dont use jenkins as a workflow orchestrator.

Comment: Yeah i know it is wild , I will try this step, Do you have any suggestion to trigger URL via ArgoCD using manual intervention. Like add new item into Deployment context menu etc....

Comment: Not sure i follow your request - `trigger URL via ArgoCD using manual intervention`. The use of `trigger` and `manual intervention` make me confused. If you want to `invoke` an endpoint manually from Argo, you have to do what I outline above...or do some weird pub-sub w/ argo-events. Im a huge fan of PostSync jobs, but you mentioned not doing that :)

Comment: I got your hints , Just a quick question : I know we can invoke various stuff as post/pre deployment actions. Can I introduce new stage [button] or new action under  deployment context menu to invoke new end point.

Comment: not that im aware of, but thats not to say im the absolute source of truth either. Just speaking from my own experience